# How to expand the countername before calling \newcounter or \addtocounter

Tags: counters

I need to do the following

```
\newcounter{problem\theenumi}
```

Clearly, `enumi` changes with time, but the counter name must be fixed NOW! So, for example, even after `\end{enumerate}` I should have access to counter `problem1`, `problem2`, etc. I played with `\expandafter` with no luck. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My impression is that you want to look at the `enumitem` package.

Comment: `\newcounter` should almost always be in the preamble of the document, why do you think you will need it in the scope where `enumi` changes?

Comment: Why don;t you use `\label` and `\ref`? Or are you after `resume` feature of `enumitem` package?

Comment: What for should I use \label and \ref? Neither I work with enumitem package. My task is to count the points associated with each \item: 
\item text \pts{5} text \pts{3} text \pts{8}
\item text \pts{7} ....
I just want to generate counter names automatically for each item. More over it is related to totcount packange as I need result from the previous compilation run.

Comment: tex has a fixed number of count registers (256 in classic tex, more in etex) it is almost always wrong to dynamically allocate them you will run out.

Comment: I think there's no need for counters here, just `\def\pts#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname problem\value{enumi}\endcsname{#1}}`. Then after using `\pts{3}` on the first item, `\csname problem1\endcsname` would expand to `3` (of course you can create a better interface).

Comment: (famous) David, I, actually, will need only 10-20 of them, not more.

Comment: Manuel, I also will need to do some additions, that's why I use counters. There are several \pts{number} per \item!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guess of what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pts}[1]{%
  \expandafter\providecommand\csname problem\theenumi\endcsname{0}% Define problem count
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \renewcommand\expandafter\csname\expandafter problem\expandafter\theenumi\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \number\numexpr\csname problem\theenumi\endcsname+#1% Sum points thus far
  }%
  (#1~points)%
}
\newcommand{\totalpoints}{Total points: \csname problem\theenumi\endcsname}% Print total points thus far
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  This is a question. \pts{5}

  This is another question. \pts{7}

  \totalpoints

  \item
  This is a new question. \pts{3}

  This is yet another question. \pts{12}

  A final question. \pts{23}

  \totalpoints
\end{enumerate}

Here is some discussion.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  This is a question. \pts{5}

  This is another question. \pts{7}

  This is a new question. \pts{3}

  This is yet another question. \pts{12}

  A final question. \pts{23}

  \totalpoints
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\pts{<points>}` prints `(<points> points)`, but also keeps a running tally of the points associated with the problem/`\item` numbered `\theenumi`.

Note: The definition of `\csname problem\theenumi\endcsname` is local to the environment in which `\pts` is first called. So, if you have a nested enumeration, one should make the definition global - a minor change in code, but it's required.